# overwrite current exe from process

Tags: c#, console

Not sure if this is good practice but bear with me.

I have a url with a new version of my app, I dont want to use any updater tools to do this.

I have 2 apps. 1 app downloads the latest version of the app, call it "Updater" a console app. The other app is the "MainApp".  I want to call the Updater app from the MainApp to replace the MainApp with the downloaded app.

```
  MessageBox.Show("We need to update the application. This might take a short while");

  System.Diagnostics.Process updateProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  updateProcess.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Updater.exe";
  updateProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
  updateProcess.Start();
  Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
  //Application.Exit();
```

The Updater app fetches the new version of the file from the args passed to the working dir of the MainApp and saves it, code below

```
        client.BaseUrl = base_url + "MainApp.exe";
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        byte[]  responseData = client.DownloadData(request);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(args[0] + "MainApp.exe", responseData);
```

This doesnt seem to quite work.  It doesnt overwrite the app!

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is why you have your launcher launch your main app, rather than having your main app launch your launcher.

Comment: yes very true and logically correct but how could I do this the way I need to as above

Comment: What I used to do is before downloading the new version, I would rename the current executable (as part of the update process - you can do it even while it's running) - then download the new version with the original file name, and then delete the renamed file.

Comment: You don't.  You won't be able to overwrite an executable that you're currently executing.

Comment: I have before with no problem.

Comment: Modern versions of windows will not allow you to modify a process that is currently running -- this is by design.

Comment: What do you call modern versions?

Comment: Id prefer not to run the Updater to call the MainApp everytime

Comment: There are probably at least 30 prior questions here asking for the same thing. Search for `[c#] application update` or `[c#] program update` or `[c#] automatic update` and you should find them.

Comment: @DanielGabriel: Since at least Windows 95, it has been impossible to overwrite or delete an executable that you are currently executing.

Comment: @JimMischel I did not overwrite or delete it. I just renamed the running executable to something else - `MainApp.exe` to `MainAppOld.exe`, so that the update would be able to create a new file called `MainApp.exe`. This way you can restart the app after the update and it'll be the new app that you are starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by having a "Restart to update" button in the main application, which performs the following steps:

1. Start the updater with a switch containing the PID of the main process.
2. The main process begins to shut down.
3. The updater finds the process with the given PID and waits for it to exit.
4. The updater overwrites the main application with the new version.
5. The updater starts the main application.
6. The updater shuts down.

Comment: How do I check if a process is finished?

Comment: Process p = Process.GetProcessById("1234");  Sorry overwrote your comment Ming Slogar

Comment: Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); assuming this is what I pass right?

Comment: int pid = 1234; // your main process id
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Exited += p_Exited;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: You should be careful about this because there may be timing issues. PIDs are not unique - if you close a process and start another one it may get the same PID. Some processes start automatically or on a schedule, so relying on the PID may result in mistaking your process with another process - especially when running on a slow machine.

Comment: @DanielGabriel: I realized that, but I'm not sure how else I would do that.